# Windows 8 hangs when I open a folder with a lot of .exe files

Tags: windows-8, freeze

I have a folder which contains a lot of .exe files. Previously, when opening the folder in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7, I never had any problems.

Now when I open that folder in Windows 8, it hangs. I have disabled SmartScreen, but I still have the same problem.

What could be the problem here? Every .exe file is more than 15 MB in size. Maybe Windows is doing an operation on them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have anti-virus installed on your system, you might find that it's doing a real-time scan on the .exe files first.  The OS will need to wait for the scan to complete before it can view the files.  If you go to a command prompt, navigate to that directory and type 'dir', does the list take a while to load there too?

Comment: nope,I don't have any antivirus.Maybe need to tried by disable Defender but it will be risky. no idea.

Comment: Is the folder on a remote machine (a server?)?  If so, does it have anti-virus?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and the cause is Windows Defender. Look with ProcessExlorer if you see this:

[image]

If you also see this, disable Defender and use a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score -2):

Disable Defender, and go download MSE (Microsoft Security Essentials) immediately. It's a way better AV software, and Defender is causing the problem anyway.

Comment: Defender = MSE. MS added the functionality of MSE into Defender in Windows 8.

Comment: No, Defender has been around since Windows 7 and it is not the same as a regular AV software. Maybe in Windows 8 it is, but not in 7.

Comment: in Win8 it is a regular AV which mostly the same functionality as MSE: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/15/protecting-you-from-malware.aspx